# Are backticks used to escape Typescript comment blocks?

Tags: typescript, express, npm

I am trying to build and run a `nest.js` app, and right out the gate, I get deluged by hundreds of errors, most of them in `.ts` files inside `node_modules`.

It seems that the compiler is interpreting anything enclosed in backticks within a comment block as code:

```
 /**
  * Set the location header to `url`.
  *
```

> node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:957:36 -
> error TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 957      * Set the location header to `url`.

I am baffled, since I haven't even touched the code. I have a fresh environment created with `nvm install 14`. The typescript was installed automatically by `npm install`.

```
martin@martin-laptop$ npm -v 
6.14.18
martin@martin-laptop$ node -v 
v14.21.3
martin@martin-laptop$ tsc --version
Version 3.9.10
```

At the top of the file there is a comment:

```
// TypeScript Version: 2.3
```

so it seems like a backwards compatibility problem. I cannot find any other metadata that would tell `tsc` to use this version, but the `package.json` in `node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core` contains the following block:

```
  "typeScriptVersion": "4.2",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "typesPublisherContentHash": "0a827d8ef2f7f9ef4c3093ee5f8b4a148b276b25d09a337a636065cf58d32616",
  "version": "4.17.33"
```

If this were so, then why would `npm` install typescript `3.9.10`?

I am trying to figure out in which `Typescript` version has the interpretation of backticks in comment blocks changed, alas nothing turns up.

Sorry for the chaotic question, but nothing makes sense to me, and I don't know how to even start. Any hints are warmheartedly welcome.